# JQuery Player with watermark effect

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, html5-video, video-player

Hi I want to play a video on my jsp page using JQuery plugin with a watermark(image/text) on top-left corner of video. I found `jPlayer` but it don't provide feature to add watermark.

One more player is freely available that is `jQplayer`. But due to unavailability of documentation, I am not able to check about it's watermark feature.

Is there any built in Jquery/HTML5 plugin that support watermark effect also? But it should be free.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure if there is or not. You could always attempt to position a watermark overtop of the player using some absolute positioning. Keep in mind though that a clever user can easily get rid of such a watermark, and if they download the raw .flv it will be watermark-less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got [html5lightbox](http://html5box.com/html5lightbox/index.php) that works with watermark. It provides easy integration of watermark on images and videos. But it also have one mistake.If you play video in full size mode then watermark is disabled.

One more plugin [JWPlayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw-player/) is created but it is not free... If you want to use it's watermark feature then you have to pay for it. Otherwise you can use it's free version.